# PHP SOAP Randomly Fails as "Could not connect to host" after working for days/hours

Tags: php, windows, soap, fastcgi

We have three web applications, on separate servers with unique inteneral/external IP addresses.  Each server is running Windows Server 2016, IIS, and PHP 7.x via FastCGI.

We're connecting to two different remote SOAP APIs from each of these web applications -- service A and service B. Since January 25th, we've been having random issues with service "A".  Once or twice a day, for about an hour, we will get a SOAP Exception of "Could not connect to host".

I understand what that message means, but I'm unsure of why it is randomly happening -- server A will have the issue, but servers B and C will connect without an issue.  And then the issue will resolve itself on server A, and then server C will start throwing SOAP exceptions later in the day.  Rebooting the server will also immediately fix the issue.

Unfortunately I don't have any access to the firewalls in front of SOAP service A, so  I can't say if its restricting connections because there are too many requests coming from a single IP, or if our requests are being dropped for another reason, or if they're even making it there.

We're trying a few different things today such as hardcoding the IP address to web service A, switching DNS providers, and doing some additional monitoring... but I've never had this issue with SOAP-heavy services in the past.

Answer (score 0):

Meh. We thought we'd eliminated DNS issues, but apparently not.

The webserver was using the datacenter's DNS servers, but somehow it would occasionally use the client's internal DNS servers... so the IP address of the webservice was changing at random times.